# javascript replace letters from array 1 with number from array 2 and calculate the sum of these numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array

array number 1:

```
let search  = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه','و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي','ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س','ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر','ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ','ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
```

array number 2:

```
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10','20', '30', '40', '50', '60','70', '80', '90', '100', '200','300', '400', '500', '600', '700','800', '900', '1000'];
```

and this is an input :

```
let word = "محمد";
```

I want in javascript search the letters of the variable `word` and replace them with the equivalent of number in the `replace` array .The replace array and the search array have the same numbers of letters and number.

The output will be:

```
م 40
ح 8
م 40
د 4

total = 92
```

```js
let word = "محمد";
let search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه', 'و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س', 'ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر', 'ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ', 'ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000'];
if (word === "") {
  document.write('the field is empty');
} else {
  w = word.split("").filter(function(ele) {
    return ele.replace(search, replace);
  }).map(function(ele) {
    return ele + ele;
  });
}
console.log(w);
```

Comment: 40 + 8 + 40 + 4 does not equal 90!

Comment: @jamiec Sorry it's 92 not 90 i edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant the expected result was 92, you can do this by forst splitting the input, then finding the index of the item in `find` and aggregating the result using `reduce` finding the value from `replace`

```js
let search  = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه','و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي','ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س','ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر','ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ','ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10','20', '30', '40', '50', '60','70', '80', '90', '100', '200','300', '400', '500', '600', '700','800', '900', '1000'];

let word = "محمد";

let result = word.split("")
                .map(x => search.indexOf(x))
                .reduce( (acc,i) => acc + parseInt(replace[i],10),0);
console.log(result);
```

You could impove this by storing integers in your `replace` array which would negate the need for `parseInt`

Comment: thank you is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a map for the two arrays:

```js
let word = "محمد";
let search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه', 'و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س', 'ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر', 'ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ', 'ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000'];

let map = Object.fromEntries(search.map((letter, i) => [letter, replace[i]]));

let w = Array.from(word, letter => map[letter]).filter(Boolean);
console.log(w);
// If you want to have a concatenated string:
console.log(w.join(","));
// Or a sum:
console.log(w.reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0));
```

Note: If your intention is to sum, or make other numerical calculations, I would suggest to make the `replace` array an array of *numbers*, not *strings*.

Comment: You could convert to numbers when you create the map.

Answer (score 0):

Logic

- Split the word into letters
- Find the index of each word from `search`.
- Find the value of the above index from  `replace` array.
- Add this in a loop

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let word = "محمد";
let search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه', 'و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س', 'ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر', 'ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ', 'ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000'];
let sum = 0;
word.split("").forEach(letter => {
  const index = replace[search.indexOf(letter)];
  console.log(`${index} ${letter}`)
  sum += +index;
});
console.log(`total = ${sum}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to replace the letters with numbers and output the total.

```js
let word = "محمد";
let search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه', 'و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س', 'ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر', 'ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ', 'ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000'];
if (word === "") {
  document.write('the field is empty');
} else {
  w = word.split("").map(function(ele) {
    return ele.replace(ele, replace[search.indexOf(ele)]);
  }).reduce((acc, next)=> acc+parseInt(next), 0)
}
console.log(w);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get abjad numbers.
so if you want to get 92, you can use blow code.

```js
let word = "محمد";
let search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه', 'و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س', 'ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر', 'ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ', 'ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
let replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000'];
if (word === "") {
  document.write('the field is empty');
} else {
  const chars = word.split('')
  var sum = 0
  chars.forEach(x => {
    const index = search.indexOf(x)
    sum += +replace[index]
  })
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

mine...

```js
const 
  val = 
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
    , 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600
    , 700, 800, 900, 1000 ]
, ref = "ابجدهوزحطيكلمنسعفصقرشتثخذظضغ"
  ;
function count (word)
  {
  c = 0
  for(let l of word) c += val[ref.indexOf(l)]
  return c
  }
  
console.log( count( "محمد") ) // 92
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a reusable solution:

```js
const word = 'محمد';
const search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه','و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي','ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س','ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر','ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ','ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
const replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10','20', '30', '40', '50', '60','70', '80', '90', '100', '200','300', '400', '500', '600', '700','800', '900', '1000'];;

const sumOfChars = (chars, replacements) => stringValue => {
  return stringValue.split('').reduce(
    (sum, char) => {
      const match = chars.indexOf(char);
      return match > -1 ? sum + Number(replacements[match]) : sum;
    },
    0
  );
}

console.log('charSumOfValues:', sumOfChars(search, replace)(word));
```

Or in two distinct functions:

```js
const word = 'محمد';
const search = ['ا', 'ب', 'ج', 'د', 'ه','و', 'ز', 'ح', 'ط', 'ي','ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س','ع', 'ف', 'ص', 'ق', 'ر','ش', 'ت', 'ث', 'خ', 'ذ','ظ', 'ض', 'غ'];
const replace = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10','20', '30', '40', '50', '60','70', '80', '90', '100', '200','300', '400', '500', '600', '700','800', '900', '1000'];;


// --- distinct utilities
const charValues = (chars, replacements) => stringValue => {
  return stringValue.split('').map(char => {
    const match = chars.indexOf(char);
    return match > -1 ? Number(replacements[match]) : 0;
  });
};

const sum = (chars) => chars.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);


const getCVs = charValues(search, replace);

console.log('values:', getCVs(word));
console.log('sum:', sum(getCVs(word)));
```